# Missing UPN and PUID claims

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying to access a particular resource from [Microsoft Graph](http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get) using the following code:

```
private const string _userUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
public static async Task<UserProfile> GetUserProfile()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _userUrl))
            {
                var token = await GetToken(true);
                req.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
                req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(req))
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    UserProfile profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(content);
                    return profile;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The GetToken returns the expected authorization Bearer Token, but when the code reaches:

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The response status code is 400 and the content "message" gives me a "Missing UPN and PUID claims".

Given that I'm fairly new to Microsoft Graph, I don't understand what exactly that means. If either I'm making a mistake on my logic or some configuration on my AAD application. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33775195/3812244), but sadly I could not understand it.

I'd greatly appreciate your input and I only ask for directions to where I should be looking at to get this resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. The API is currently lacking support for users who login to AAD using external accounts (like Microsoft Account). We are working on addressing this, and expect an update when it is available.

In the mean time, try creating a regular AAD user using Azure portal, and try the API as that user.

[Update-2016-2-16:Fix is now in place. Please give it a shot]

Comment: Do you have an update as to any potential timeframes this may take as it is currently a huge hold up on my project. Thanks.

Comment: Current timeframe for the fix is in the next 2-3 weeks. Expect an update here once the fix is live.

Comment: @sriramd, I'll mark your reply as an answer, but I'd greatly appreciate if you could edit your post when the fix have been put into place. Many thanks!

Comment: The fix is now in place. Please give it a try.